# Xamarin.Android: How to capture Button events defined in the OnClick XML attribute?

Tags: c#, android, xml, xamarin

I have this Button inside a RelativeLayout which is included as part of a custom ListView row Layout.

```xml
<Button
    p1:text="Edit"
    p1:layout_width="75dp"
    p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
    p1:id="@+id/editButton"
    p1:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    p1:background="@drawable/btn_blue"
    p1:textColor="@color/white"
    p1:focusable="false"
    p1:layout_below="@id/sparyTableLayout"
    p1:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    p1:onClick="myClickHandler" />
```

When the user clicks the Button, I want the Button to call this function:

```cs
public void myClickHandler(View v)
{
    Console.WriteLine ((v as Button).Text);
}
```

However, I am getting this error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method myClickHandler(View) in the activity   class Test_Project.MyActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'editButton'
```

I am trying to differentiate between the different buttons I have in that ListView. Also, each row has multiple Buttons.

**Edit:**

Don't use tags in Buttons it can cause performance drop during ListView scrolling. The solution below is a better option.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add the attribute `[Java.Interop.Export]` to your click handler method:

```
[Java.Interop.Export("myClickHandler")] // The value found in android:onClick attribute.
public void myClickHandler(View v) // Does not need to match value in above attribute.
{
    Console.WriteLine ((v as Button).Text);
}
```

This will expose the method to Java via the [Generated Callable Wrapper](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/java_integration_overview/android_callable_wrappers/) for your activity so it can invoked from the Java runtime.

See:

1. [Mono For Android 4.2 release notes](http://docs.xamarin.com/releases/android/mono_for_android_4/mono_for_android_4.2/) within the section titled "Exporting arbitrary Java member for better Java integration".

### Important Note

Using `[Java.Interop.Export]` requires you to add the `Mono.Android.Export` assembly to your project.

**Therefore this feature is only available for Indie and higher licences.**

Comment: I think this is available to all developers now. Great answer though! I've looked for hours on the interwebs for this.