# ImageButton click does not work

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I tried two different ways to set up the event for an ImageButton but neither has worked. First I tried by adding onClick in the axml file:

```
<ImageButton
    android:src="@drawable/homeInfoButtonImages"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/homeInfoButton"
    android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="600dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:onClick="infoButtonClick" />
```

In the Activity.cs:

```
    private void infoButtonClick()
    {
        Console.Write("Clicked");
    }
```

The app crashes as soon the button is clicked.

The second method I tried in Activity.cs:

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Home);

        // Create your application here
        ImageButton button = FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.homeInfoButton);

        button.Click += delegate
        {
            infoButtonClick();
        };
    }

    private void infoButtonClick()
    {
        Console.Write("Clicked");
    }
```

Nothing happens when the button is clicked...

What could be causing this issue?

Comment: Could you post the logcat output for the crash? I suspect you haven't added [Java.Interop.Export("infoButtonClick")] as an attribute to your infoButtonClick method.

See this similar answer by me:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20197848/xamarin-android-how-to-capture-button-events-defined-in-the-onclick-xml-attribu

Answer (score 2):

In the method that is called from the onClick attribute on the xml, you must pass an argument of the view, and it must be public:

```
public void infoButtonClick(View v)
{
  Console.Write("Clicked");
}
```

As you can read [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html)

Answer (score 1):

Please  remove `Console.Write("Clicked");` and test.

Answer (score 0):

I code using java in eclipse.I had the same problem. So I dont know whether it will work for you.

try **public** void infoButtonClick() instead of private.

This solution worked for me. Thought it might help.

Answer (score 0):

Console.WriteLine might have some unexpected behaviour (at least what I have experienced). The below code works fine for me.

```
        FindViewById<ImageButton> (Resource.Id.imageButton1).Click += (s, e) =>
            Log.Info (s.ToString (), "Image button clicked!");
```