# Xamarin.Android vs Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I am `C#` guy and trying to explore the `Xamarin` for making android apps using `C#` ( Keep your calm Java guys :) .

So my questions are -

- Is there any difference between them except the language usage ?
- Is there any constraint on using Xamarin.Android as compared to
  actual Android?
- Can I do everything using Xamarin.Android as we can do with Android
  using `Java`?

Comment: That's a *huge* question. The typical Xamarin mindset seems to be to allow ready access to the 80% of the stuff everyone's got to do while not preventing those who need to get more granular from accessing "native" resources. You might listen to [this episode of Hallway Conversations with Chris Miller](http://hallwayconversations.com/podcast/episode-023-the-business-case-for-xamarin-with-chris-miller/) to get a better idea of what I'm trying to say. It's iOS biased, but they talk Android and Xamarin in general.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, this is a whale of a question. Here's some starting information :)

### Is there any difference between them except the language usage ?

Yes, a few major differences. The most significant being how apps are executed and the final APK size.

**Application Execution**

Xamarin runs the Dalvik (or ART) run-time alongside the Mono run-time and uses [Android Callable Wrappers](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/java_integration_overview/android_callable_wrappers/) to communicate between the two. This means you get all the benefits of C# (LINQ, async/await, .NET API) within the Android App Framework.

This is a bit big to explain on Stack Overflow so here is some reading for insight:

- [Java Integration Overview](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/java_integration_overview/)
- [Xamarin Android Architecture](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/under_the_hood/architecture/)

**APK Size**

The other significant difference is the size of the APK Xamarin generates compared to a vanilla Java APK. A common complaint is that Xamarin.Android package sizes are huge and yes, that can be the case. As a rule of thumb, Xamarin.Android apps will be at least 2.5mb larger than a Java APK as the core components of the run-time are included in the APK.

Debug builds that use the shared run-time end up being a comparable size to a Java APK. However, this is only because the `ContentProvider` that initializes Monodroid extracts the dependencies from an pre-installed APK (Mono.Android.*) rather than your apps package.

Building a typical Hello World app in release mode and linking using `Sdk Assemblies` would produce a final APK of around 3mb. The image below shows the final makeup of the APK and what is using all that memory:

[image]

Xamarin does a great job of explaining these limitations in their [Application Package Sizes](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/application_package_sizes/) article.

In regards to other differences, it's best to read the [Android Advanced Topics](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/) section of the Xamarin site.

### Is there any constraint on using Xamarin.Android as compared to actual Android?

None that I have encountered so far (built 3 commercial apps, working on a 4th at work, working on another at home, played around a lot). The main constraints I have encountered come down to licensing levels in Xamarin.

- [Here is an example.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20197848/xamarin-android-how-to-capture-button-events-defined-in-the-onclick-xml-attribu)

### Can I do everything using Xamarin.Android as we can do with Android using Java?

In general, yes. All the Java APIs are exposed via the `Java.*` namespace. Once you have learnt the conventions of Xamarin and can read Java code, it's generally straight forward to translate Java to C#.

### Summary

Take all of this with a grain of salt; I've only given you a teeny tiny summary of Xamarin! It's a huge tool and the best way to learn it is to download a few of the sample apps ([here](https://github.com/xamarin/mobile-samples)), hack them and figure out if it's right for your dev team.

Comment: Would you mind saying a few words about the size of the resulting apps? I believe that critics talk about this, saying a minimum Xamarin app is several megabytes or more.

Comment: Sure I can, will have to be later in the day though. I've been eating lunch while answering this.

Comment: Bon appetit! (Or bon apps?)

Comment: It may be a month later but I finally got around to updating this answer with some details on Xamarin.Android app package sizes. Enjoy @RenniePet.

Comment: Is it the 3MB Mono stuff that makes the app take so long to start up?