# My Xamarin.Android app crushes during debugging and I cannot find any mistakes

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xaml, xamarin

Here is what I get:"Unhandled Exception:  Java.Lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method TwoClicked(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'two'"
Here is my XAML code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:minWidth="25px"
android:minHeight="25px">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1">
    <TextView
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/result"
        android:textStyle="bold|normal|italic"
        android:textSize="52dp"
        android:textAlignment="textEnd"
        android:paddingEnd="10dp" />
    <Button
            android:id="@+id/CE"
            android:layout_gravity="left|top"
            android:text="CE"
            android:height="90dp"
            android:width="94dp"
            android:textSize="25dp" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/seven"
            android:layout_gravity="left|top"
            android:text="7"
            android:height="90dp"
            android:width="94dp"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:onClick="SevenClicked" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/four"
            android:layout_gravity="left|top"
            android:text="4"
            android:height="90dp"
            android:width="94dp"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:onClick="FourClicked" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/one"
            android:layout_gravity="left|top"
            android:text="1"
            android:height="90dp"
            android:width="94dp"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:onClick="OneClicked" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/backspace"
            android:layout_gravity="left|top"
            android:text="&lt;-"
            android:height="90dp"
            android:width="94dp"
            android:textSize="25dp" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/leftBracket"
            android:layout_gravity="left|top"
            android:text="("
            android:height="90dp"
            android:width="94dp"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:onClick="LeftBracketClicked" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/eight"
            android:layout_gravity="left|top"
            android:text="8"
            android:height="90dp"
            android:width="94dp"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:onClick="EightClicked" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/five"
            android:layout_gravity="left|top"
            android:text="5"
            android:height="90dp"
            android:width="94dp"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:onClick="FiveClicked" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/two"
            android:layout_gravity="left|top"
            android:text="2"
            android:height="90dp"
            android:width="94dp"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:onClick="TwoClicked" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/zero"
            android:layout_gravity="left|top"
            android:text="0"
            android:height="90dp"
            android:width="94dp"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:onClick="ZeroClicked" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/rightBracket"
            android:layout_gravity="left|top"
            android:text=")"
            android:height="90dp"
            android:width="94dp"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:onClick="RightBracketClicked" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/nine"
            android:layout_gravity="left|top"
            android:height="90dp"
            android:width="94dp"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:text="9"
            android:onClick="NineClicked" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/six"
            android:layout_gravity="left|top"
            android:text="6"
            android:height="90dp"
            android:width="94dp"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:onClick="SixClicked" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/three"
            android:layout_gravity="left|top"
            android:text="3"
            android:height="90dp"
            android:width="94dp"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:onClick="ThreeClicked" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/period"
            android:layout_gravity="left|top"
            android:text="."
            android:height="90dp"
            android:width="94dp"
            android:textSize="25dp" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/plus"
            android:layout_gravity="left|top"
            android:text="+"
            android:height="90dp"
            android:width="94dp"
            android:textSize="25dp" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/minus"
            android:layout_gravity="left|top"
            android:text="-"
            android:height="90dp"
            android:width="94dp"
            android:textSize="25dp" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/multiplication"
            android:layout_gravity="left|top"
            android:text="x"
            android:height="90dp"
            android:width="94dp"
            android:textSize="25dp" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/division"
            android:layout_gravity="left|top"
            android:text="/"
            android:height="90dp"
            android:width="94dp"
            android:textSize="25dp" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/equals"
            android:layout_gravity="left|top"
            android:text="="
            android:height="90dp"
            android:width="94dp"
            android:textSize="25dp" />
    </GridLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my C# code:

```
using Xamarin;
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Support.V7.App;

namespace Calculator
{
[Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme",
MainLauncher = true)]
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    public TextView result;


    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

        result = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.result);

    }

    [Java.Interop.Export("ZeroClicked")]
    public void ZeroClicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {

        result.Text = result.Text + "0";

    }
    [Java.Interop.Export("OneClicked")]
    public void OneClicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {

        result.Text = result.Text + "1";

    }
    [Java.Interop.Export("TwoClicked")]
    public void TwoClicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {

        result.Text = result.Text + "2";

    }
    [Java.Interop.Export("ThreeClicked")]
    public void ThreeClicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        result.Text = result.Text + "3";

    }
    [Java.Interop.Export("FourClicked")]
    public void FourClicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        result.Text = result.Text + "4";
    }
    [Java.Interop.Export("FiveClicked")]
    public void FiveClicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        result.Text = result.Text + "5";
    }
    [Java.Interop.Export("SixClicked")]
    public void SixClicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        result.Text = result.Text + "6";
    }
    [Java.Interop.Export("SevenClicked")]
    public void SevenClicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        result.Text = result.Text + "7";
    }
    [Java.Interop.Export("EightClicked")]
    public void EightClicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        result.Text = result.Text + "8";
    }
    [Java.Interop.Export("NineClicked")]
    public void NineClicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        result.Text = result.Text + "9";
    }
    [Java.Interop.Export("PlusClicked")]
    public void PlusClicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        result.Text = result.Text + "+";
    }
    [Java.Interop.Export("MinusClicked")]
    public void MinusClicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        result.Text = result.Text + "-";
    }
    [Java.Interop.Export("MultiplicationClicked")]
    public void MultiplicationClicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        result.Text = result.Text + "*";
    }
    [Java.Interop.Export("DivisionClicked")]
    public void DivisionClicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        result.Text = result.Text + "/";
    }
    [Java.Interop.Export("LeftBracketClicked")]
    public void LeftBracketClicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        result.Text = result.Text + "(";
    }


    [Java.Interop.Export("RightBracketClicked")]
    public void RightBracketClicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        result.Text = result.Text + ")";
    }
}
```

}
Could you please help me?
I get this error when I press a button in debugging mode:[My error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2oAfD.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void TwoClicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{

    result.Text = result.Text + "2";

}
```

should be

```
public void TwoClicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    result.Text = result.Text + "2";
}
```

same with all other onClick methods

Comment: Thank you for your help, but it still crushes whenever I click a button

Comment: The access modifier needs to be public before it can be recognised by Android

Answer (score 1):

To capture the onclick method when you define your onclick on xml use `Java.Interop.Export` like in here [Xamarin.Android: How to capture Button events defined in the OnClick XML attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20197848/xamarin-android-how-to-capture-button-events-defined-in-the-onclick-xml-attribu#20210562)

My suggestion will be define your onclick method on your Activity like

```
var buttonSeven = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.seven);
buttonSeven +=(object sender, EventArgs e) => 
                {
                    //anything you wanna do when button clicked
                    result.Text=result.Text+"7"
                };
```

Comment: Should I type anything between those brackets?;

Comment: yes. between those bracket is anything you wanna do when button clicked

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use the `android:onClick` in your AXML to auto-magically bind to a click function, you have to export those C# methods to the Java wrapper that is generated so they can be found in the Java code and thus call back into your C# via Mono/JNI:

So a AXML based `onClick`:

```
android:onClick="javaNineClicked"
```

Has to have a matching `Export` with the same name:

```
[Java.Interop.Export("javaNineClicked")]
public void NineClicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    result.Text = result.Text + "9";
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I get an error, that states:"
Error Failed to create JavaTypeInfo for class: Calculator.MainActivity due to System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
    
"

Comment: @vit Your layout onclick methods do not match your export attrubutes

Comment: Okay, now they match and I still get an error. P.S. I`ve added reference to Java.Interop