# Button onClick not binding to method in Activity

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

So I'm trying to test out adding a click event to a `Button` in an .axml file that my main `Activity` uses. I've gone through a lot of other threads and I have followed the code provided as best I can. However I am getting the following exception when I run my code.

```
Java.Lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method testClick(View) 
in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute 
defined on view class android.widget.Button with id 'login'
```

In Main.axml

```
  <Button
      android:text="Login"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:layout_weight="2"
      android:onClick="testClick"
      android:id="@+id/login" />
```

In Main.cs

```
public class Main : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Android.OS.Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
    }

    public void testClick(View view)
    {
        //Show alert saying clicked...
    }
}
```

Am I missing some configuration, or include to get this to work perhaps?

Comment: did you build it or try to restart VS and build again?

Comment: Probably your SetContentView method is wrong, try using it with R.layout.main. Like this SetContentView(R.layout.main)

Comment: @LukeVo Restarting VS and rebuilding didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always do this :

```
Button button1 = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id. login);
button1.Click += delegate => {
 //Show alert saying clicked...
};
```

If you don't want to use this way, you should `Export` your method first as follow take a look on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20210562/4385913):

```
[Export("testClick")]
public void testClick(View view)
{
    //Show alert saying clicked...
}
```

If those didn't work add a reference to `Mono.Android.Export.dll` and then in your `Activity` put this

```
[Java.Interop.Export("testClick")]
public void testClick(View view)
{
    //Show alert saying clicked...
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Exporting it and adding that file was exactly the issue!

Comment: Glad to help :D

Answer (score 0):

Please try after inheriting interface  View.IOnclicklistener :

```
public class Main: AppcompatActivity, View.IonClickListener
```

It help to implement the onclick method of the interface like you given:

```
public void testClick(View view)
    {
        //Show alert saying clicked...
    }
```